# DataContext does not propagate to children (non-visual) in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

```
<k:GridView Name="_masterGridView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProductLocationList}" 
            SelectedItem="{Binding ProductLocationSelected}">
<!-- DataContext does not propagate here automatically in user control... why? -->
    <k:GridView.ExportOptions>
         <k:GridViewExportOptions Title="Production Location Management">
             <k:SearchCriteria >
                 <k:SearchCriterion Title="End Date"
                                    Value="{Binding SearchEndDate}"
                                    ValueFormat="g" />
             </k:SearchCriteria>
         </k:GridViewExportOptions>
    </k:GridView.ExportOptions>
<!-- to here -->
```

I have to do this hack and it only propagates to GridViewExport option
The hack is in the GridView class...

```
public GridViewExportOptions ExportOptions
{
    get { return _exportOptions; }
    set
    {
        _exportOptions = value;

        if (value != null)
        {
            ExportOptions.SetBinding(FrameworkContentElement.DataContextProperty,
                new Binding("DataContext")
                {
                    Source = this,
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to add your `GridViewExportOptions` as a logical child. Effectively, your `GridViewExportOptions` would have to derive from `FrameworkElement`. When your property is changed, you'd have to [AddLogicalChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.addlogicalchild.aspx) on your `GridView` (and RemoveLogicalChild to remove the old value, if any). Then you'd have to override [LogicalChildren](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.logicalchildren.aspx) on your `GridView` and include your option.

You would need to do this in your `GridViewExportOptions` class as well, with respect to it's "children".

Comment: I was thinking that you confirmed it! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you CodeNaked. This answer led me to a solution for a different but similar problem where I was defining my own custom ContentControl but had not overridden the LogicalChildren property.